# Figure in background

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tcolorbox, backgrounds

I have a box built with `tcolorbox` with blue color and I want to insert a figure inside this box. However, the space used by figure is white. How can I eliminate this blanck space and the background where my figure is located is homogeneous?
Here my output:

[image]

The code is presented below:

The code is presented below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1cm,left=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs,tikz,fancyhdr,array}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exer}{breakable,enhanced,before skip=5mm,after skip=5mm,title={Exercício \thetcbcounter},attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-3mm},colbacktitle=blue!25,boxsep=3mm,boxrule=1.5pt,colframe=blue,colback=blue!5,coltitle=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{exer}
(***)Prove, usando coordenadas cilíndricas \textit{modificada}, que o volume de um cone elíptico de semi-eixos $a$ e $b$ e altura $h$ é
$$V=\frac{\pi}{3}abh.$$

\includegraphics{cilin.png}

\end{exer}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If your PNG is not with transparent background, then I think you can't do anything about it in LaTeX. You may either modify your image to add a transparent background or reproduce it in Ti*k*Z directly into your TeX file.

Comment: This can be done using a graphics editor (like gimp).  You have to add a transparent layer (alpha channel) and delete anything white.

Answer (score 7):

I think is much easier to use  an external tool.

For odd jobs I use a free online service.

With ImageMagick (you only need `convert.exe`, the background color is -in this case- `ffffff`)

Run from the command line:

`convert cillinder.png -fuzz 4% -transparent "#ffffff" cillinder-transparent4.png`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1cm,left=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs,tikz,fancyhdr,array}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exer}{breakable,enhanced,before skip=5mm,after skip=5mm,title={Exercício \thetcbcounter},attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-3mm},colbacktitle=blue!25,boxsep=3mm,boxrule=1.5pt,colframe=blue,colback=blue!5,coltitle=black}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{exer}
        (***)Prove, usando coordenadas cilíndricas \textit{modificada}, que o volume de um cone elíptico de semi-eixos $a$ e $b$ e altura $h$ é
        $$V=\frac{\pi}{3}abh.$$     
        \includegraphics[scale=3]{cillinder.png}        
    \end{exer}
    
        \begin{exer}
        (***)Prove, usando coordenadas cilíndricas \textit{modificada}, que o volume de um cone elíptico de semi-eixos $a$ e $b$ e altura $h$ é
        $$V=\frac{\pi}{3}abh.$$         
        \includegraphics[scale=3]{cillinder-transparent4}
    \end{exer}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Answer (score 6):

This is a workaround. It can't solve the same problem with any picture, but this one is not very difficult to draw with Ti*k*Z.

As you can see, the code for drawing the figure is quite brief. The axes and an approximate curve drawn in two pieces (back and front). There are more lines for style (shadings, isometric,...) than for the drawing itself.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage   [portuguese]  {babel}
\usepackage   [top=1cm,
               bottom=1.5cm,
               right=1cm,
               left=1cm]    {geometry}
\usepackage                 {graphics}
\usepackage                 {tikz}
\usepackage   [most]        {tcolorbox}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exer}{breakable,enhanced,before skip=5mm,after skip=5mm,title={Exercício \thetcbcounter},attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-3mm},colbacktitle=blue!25,boxsep=3mm,boxrule=1.5pt,colframe=blue,colback=blue!5,coltitle=black}

% TikZ styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% shadings
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{backblue}{100pt}
{%
color(0pt)=(blue!40);
color(60pt)=(white);
color(100pt)=(blue!20)
}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{frontblue}{100pt}
{%
color(0pt)=(blue!40);
color(40pt)=(white);
color(100pt)=(blue!60)
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% isometric perspective (axes dimensions)
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% other styles
\tikzset
{%
  isometric/.style={x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0 cm,\zz cm)}},
  front/.style={blue,thick,shading=frontblue,fill opacity=0.8},
  back/.style={blue,thick,shading=backblue}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{exer}
(***)Prove, usando coordenadas cilíndricas \textit{modificada}, que o volume de um cone elíptico de semi-eixos $a$ e $b$ e altura $h$ é
\[V=\frac{\pi}{3}abh.\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric]
\def\r{-20} % rotation angle
% cylinder, back
\draw[back] (315:1) arc (315:135:1) --
   plot[samples=46,domain=135:315] ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{2+0.5*sin(3*\x-\r)}) -- cycle;
% axes
\draw[thick,-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0)   node [left]  {$x$};
\draw[thick,-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0)   node [right] {$y$};
\draw[thick,-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3.5) node [right] {$z$};
% cylinder, front
\draw[front] (135:1) arc (135:-45:1) --
   plot[samples=46,domain=-45:135] ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{2+0.5*sin(3*\x-\r)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exer}

\end{document}
```

[image]